# EXC_BAD_ACCESS ( code=2 ) in recursive function call

Tags: c++, opencv, recursion

I implemented a recursive function to do a region growing in a Mat mask and count the number os pixels of this region and the number os intersected pixels compared to another mask.
I tested with images with small mask regions and it works fine. However, when I call the function for images with big mask regions I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS ( code=2). Is it related to the amount of times the recursive function is called?

this is where the recursive function is called:

```
void calculateDice(Mat gtMask, Mat src)
{
    Mat mask;
    src.copyTo(mask);
    int positive = 0;
    int negative = 0;
    imshow("mask", mask);
    for(int i = 0; i < mask.rows; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < mask.cols; j++)
        {
            Scalar intensity = mask.at<uchar>(i, j);
            if(intensity.val[0] > 200)
            {
                int total = 0;
                int amountIn = 0;
                getMaskIntersection(mask, gtMask, i, j, amountIn, total);
                double percentage = (amountIn*100)/total;
                cout<<"porcentagem dice "<<percentage<<endl;
                if(percentage>=40)
                    positive++;
                else
                    negative++;
            }
        }


    cout<<"verdadeiro positivo "<<positive << " falso positivo "<<negative<<endl;
    //return 0;
}
```

this is the recursive function:

```
void getMaskIntersection(Mat &mask, Mat gtMask, int i, int j, int &amountIn, int &total)
{
    Scalar intensity;
     intensity = mask.at<uchar>(i,j);
    if(intensity.val[0] < 200)
    {
        return;
    }
    else{
        total++;
        Scalar intensity2 = gtMask.at<uchar>(i,j);

        if(intensity2.val[0]>10)
        {
            amountIn++;
        }

        mask.at<uchar>(i, j) = 0;
        if(i < mask.rows)
            getMaskIntersection(mask, gtMask, i+1, j, amountIn, total);
        if(i > 0)
            getMaskIntersection(mask, gtMask, i-1, j, amountIn, total);
        if(j < mask.cols)
            getMaskIntersection(mask, gtMask, i, j+1, amountIn, total);
        if(j > 0)
            getMaskIntersection(mask, gtMask, i, j-1, amountIn, total);
    }

}
```

The exception is thrown always in the first first line of the recursive function, where Scalar intensity is declared.

Comment: You're passing `gtMask` into `getMaskIntersection` by value, which will create a copy of it.  This could be using up all the available memory.

Comment: you're checking `i` to be less than `rows` but then pass it in incremented where it could be equal to `rows` (out of bounds). Same with `j`